# Where should I store passwords for an auto-login chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

I want to write some extension to auto-login me to a specific site (Moodle if that matters).
What is the best practice for that use case of storing the user's password in that extension?

in `background.js` / `chrome.storage` or something else?
is there anyway to access chrome's password manager and pull the data from there?

I saw some similar questions but some has no good answer and some are just to old so maybe there is something new.

thanks.